# Java formatting with set amount of spaces

Tags: java, formatting, format, indentation, spaces

How would I format a set amount of spaces for results to look like these?
Trying to get the exact spacing types between the Grade, Count and % outputs. Count column should match up with the letter t. The one I'm especially confused about is % due to the indentation differences depending on the number; e.g. if it is 100.00 the 1 should align with %, multiple of 10 i.e. 10-99.00 should be 1 space after %, and 0.00 should be 2 spaces after %.

Thanks in advance!

*Grade     Count    %

*__________________________

*F            0      0.00

*P            1     20.00

*C            2     40.00

*D            0      0.00

*HD           2     40.00

Comment: Have a look at the `String.format` method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...) (`System.out.printf` is also pretty much identical), as well as the formatting guide: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax You can use one of the padding rules (like `%[...]s`) to control how many spaces appear before or after the arguments of each data line (grade, count, percentage). You shouldn't have to test the actual value to determine the amount of space.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called "fixed column width" formatting.  The easiest way to achieve it is to use the `printf` method.  In your case, you'd do something like this:

```
    System.out.println("Grade Count %");
    System.out.println("----- ----- ------");
    for (Grade g : grades) {
        System.out.printf("%-5s %5d %6.2f%n", 
            g.getGrade(), g.getCount(), g.getPercent());
    }
```

The first argument to `printf` is a format string that includes both fixed text (here just some spaces) and format specifiers that start with a `%` and end with a letter; the remaining arguments are the data to be formatted.  Here's a brief breakdown of the format string in this example:

- `%-5s` matches with the `g.getGrade()` argument; the `5` means a fixed field width of 5 columns, the `-` means left-justify, the `s` means we're formatting a `String` argument
- `%5d` matches with the `g.getCount()` argument; the `d` means we're formatting a decimal integer (`int`, `long`, or `BigDecimal`) number, `5` is the field width, and the lack of a `-` implies right-justification;
- `%6.2f` matches with the `g.getPercent()` argument; the `f` means we're formatting a floating-point (`float`, `double` or `BigDecimal`) number, `6` is the overall field width, `.2` means there will be 2 digits after the decimal point, and no `-` means to right-justify.

For a more complete discussion, read [format strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: My bad!  `%-6.2f`  should have been `%6.2f`. (without the `-`) to right-align the percents.